# Setting up autocompletion for Scala in JMonkey Engine

Tags: scala, opengl, netbeans, autocomplete, jmonkeyengine

I would like to use Scala and JMonkey Engine to create a small game. It should be nothing more than a test wether the engine is fun to use. I'm new to JMonkey and therefore don't know the usual method calls. Something like autocompletion would be nice but currently even the standard Scala autocompletion doesn's work. I downloaded JMonkey Engine, installed the standard Netbeans Scala Plugins. Now I can create Scala objects and classes but nothing more. Can you give me advice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have really the **latest** version of the Scala Plugin? It seems to work (at least for me).

Just in case (it is a little bit hard to find):

- For Scala 2.8: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/36598/nbscala-2-8-x
- For Scala 2.9: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/38999/nbscala-2-9-x-0-9

BTW, there is a Scala 3D Engine (but still pretty alpha): [Sgine](http://www.sgine.org/)

Comment: Yes I have installed the latest versions:

Comment: the new typesafe stack for Scala 2.9.0.1 and the newest Netbeans plugin for Scala 2.9.x